# How can I generate ip address by specific ip range in shell scriptting?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh

I need to generate a list of IP-addresses (IPv4) in sh script. I have start and end addresses, for example;

> Start : 5.38.0.0 End   : 5.38.127.255

**How can I print all the addresses ?**

Comment: Check this [\[ answer \]](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/169100/25919) and try to post some code along with the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the below script as

```
#!/bin/bash
ip1=( $(echo "$1" | sed 's/\./ /g') )
ip2=( $(echo "$2" | sed 's/\./ /g') )


for i in $(seq ${ip1[0]} ${ip2[0]})
 do
  for j in $(seq ${ip1[1]} ${ip2[1]})
   do
    for k in $(seq ${ip1[2]} ${ip2[2]})
     do
      for l in $(seq ${ip1[3]} ${ip2[3]})
       do
       printf "%d.%d.%d.%d\n" $i $j $k $l
       done
     done
   done
done
```

as `ip_generator`, do `chmod +x ip_generator` and run it like :

```
./ip_generator  5.38.0.0 5.38.127.255
```

ie, in the format

```
./ip_generator  start_address end_address
```

Comment: And I hope there is a more elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You have in fact a string made up of 4 numbers
each of the numbers runs from 0 to 255

So break up the Start String
START
and in the right most number add 1
recombine and output
BREAK out if the numbers in the string match the end number

loop while the right most number is <= 255
and set the right most number to 0
Then set the next number up by 1 
recombine and output
and 
repeat from START

Comment: Can you write example script please ?